# Forward and Backward Crosstalk

Tags: pcb, electromagnetism, electromagnetic, interference, crosstalk

I have some basic questions about crosstalk. My reference for this question is [this](https://www.polarinstruments.com/support/si/AP8164.html) website.

This website introduces crosstalk in this way:

> Crosstalk is the unwanted coupling of energy between two or more adjacent lines. This unwanted coupling can change the required signal. Crosstalk size estimations are commonly divided into two separation calculations:
>
> - Energy that is coupled from the actual signal line, the aggressor, onto a quiet passive victim line so that the transferred energy "travels back" to the start of the victim line. This is known as the backward or near-end crosstalk.
> - Energy that is coupled from the active signal line, the aggressor, onto a quiet passive victim line so that the transferred energy
>   "travels forward" to the end of the victim line. This known as forward
>   or far-end crosstalk.
>
> If the victim line is not terminated at both ends in its characteristic impedance the induced spurious signals can reflect at the ends of the line and travel in the opposite direction down the line. Thus a reflected near-end crosstalk can end up appearing at the far end — and vice versa.

**First question**: how can we define the end and the start of the victim line? Since it is passive, I think it is arbitrary if we call a termination "end" and the other one "start" or viceversa. So, I'd say that a backward crosstalk may be seen as a forward crosstalk or viceversa. Is this true?

**Second question**: which is the cause of the simultaneous presence of both types of crosstalk? Impedance mismatch? If the passive line is closed at the beginning with matched load and at the end with mismatched load, will there be both crosstalks or only forward crosstalk?

Let's see now more in detail the forward crosstalk.

> The far-end crosstalk can be considered as an effect caused by the difference in velocity between the odd and even modes of propagation and thus a difference in edge arrival times at the end of the line — see Figures 2 and 3 below.

[image]

**Third question**: odd and even modes have not been defined. What are they and why do they propagate with different velocities? And why this phenomenon determines interference (crosstalk)?

**Fourth question**: in the analysis of directional couplers I have found an oscillating behaviour of power along the lines with respect to the position (shown in the following picture). This situation is not considered in the previous analysis. Is it a different situation (since the directional coupler have a high coupling factor, while the previous analysis considers weakly coupled lines)?
[image]

Comment: I would say that it is confusing but, what can you expect from a site that is trying to sell you PCB tools? There doesn't appear to be a way to access the link you provided from the home page either so it's not like it's some theory that they are pushing out. I'd not consider it very useful if I were you.